# Object / Edge Bevel with angle other than 45 degrees

Tags: modeling, bevel

Discovered blender 2 weeks ago, so < Noob.  Loving it so far!!  I'm looking for a way to create an effect similar to the bevel modifier, but which produces an angle other than 45 degrees.  For example, I'd like to create a cube object that has a draft angle on the left, right, front, and back faces (not top, and bottom) of 80 degrees instead of 90 degrees.  The resulting top square face would be slightly smaller than the bottom square face, with the edge faces sloping slightly.  A sort of standard trapezoidal shape.  Any advice on how to create this geometry?

Edit: I misused the term "bevel" I think.  What I'm looking to do is create a consistent angle between faces.  In the 2nd picture I'm attempting to create a 10 degree angle (100 - 90 = 10).  One issue is I don't know how to enter values (e.g. 80 degrees, 110 degrees) into the protractor.  I'm attempting to move the edges and "snap to" the protractor in this case, which is probably not a good way to do this.  I can move, or scale the edges to create the desired angle, but it is time consuming to calculate the desired coordinates of the vertices, etc.  Just looking for suggestions.  Thanks!

This is essentially what I'm going for, which isn't a "bevel."  Although I may only want to modify 1, 2, or 3 of the side faces, and exclude the other faces.
[image: Cube]

[image: Angle Image]

Note: in the second picture it would be undesirable to move all 4 bottom edges of the "rectangle" because it intersects another piece of the object.  So I would want to move only 3 of the 4 bottom edges in that case.  Maybe this should be a separate object?  I don't know, like I said imanoob.

Comment: Scale down top face? I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Could you post some screenshot?

Comment: Good suggestion, and it works, but I'm missing how to get the precision out of the scale tool.  It appears I can set a scale factor (e.g. 1.10) while scaling, but is there a way to monitor the angle between two edges, or faces while I am sliding the scale tool?  Ideally what I'm looking for is a way to add this angle to a bunch of selected faces at once, and be able to turn it on & off, like a modifier.  Hope that makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found an ok solution.  In the transform toolbar there is a "face info" section.  Adding a check in the box next to angle allows one to see the angle while making adjustments to the face edges.

Answer (score 0):

- In the overlays panel, turn on Face Angle

  [image]
- If you transform any vertex/edge now, all affected measurements will be displayed live

  [image]